# RetrieveMultipleRequest.MinActiveRowVersion what it this and when is it ever not -1

Tags: dynamics-crm

I have been investigating ways to synchronise incremental changes with dynamics crm.

I stumbled accross the MinActiveRowVersion property of RetrieveMultipleRequest

```
        var orgService = serviceProvider.GetOrganisationService();
        using (orgService as IDisposable)
        {

            var accounts = orgService.RetrieveMultiple(new QueryExpression("account") { ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("accountid") });
            Console.WriteLine("min active is: " + accounts.MinActiveRowVersion);

        }
```

This property always returns "-1" during my testing, even when I am trying to simulate transactions going on in the background, but its tricky to do.

My understanding of MinActiveRowVersion from a SQL perspective comes from here:-

[[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb839514.aspx][1]](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb839514.aspx%5d%5b1%5d)

So my question is, is anyone able to clarify exactly what this MinActiveRowVersion property is, because I can't find anything useful in the SDK documentation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge and experience it is never used and will always equal`-1`. Under the cover it is hard coded as a `long` and converted to a `string` when the `EntityCollection` object is built - so it will always be `-1`.

The [SDK defines it as](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.entitycollection.minactiverowversion.aspx) **"the lowest active row version value"** which implies it is related to SQL row versions, but CRM does not make use of this field. It is defined the same in the CRM 2011 and CRM 2013 SDKs.

In CRM 4 we had the `BusinessEntityCollection`, which was `EntityCollection`'s predecessor. It had an unused `string` property called `Version`.

My guess, back when the CRM 2011 was being designed it got added for some potential functionality - which didn't survive - and never removed before it went RTM. Once it was released the product team didn't want to change the class definition and break existing code so they just left it there to live on returning `-1`.

Comment: Thanks @nicknow, i suspected something like this. Kind of sloppy of the dynamics team in my opinion - they should have atleast marked it as obsolete / deprecated. Anyway... thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

MinActiveRowVersion is returned in the fetch response if the fetch query contained the attribute min-active-row-version=1. (In the same tag where page and distinct attributes are specified.)

We rely on this behavior for years. (And yes, we use it for synchronization of changes. Rowversion appears to be the only reliable tool. Note that not all Dynamics entities have Rowversion column. E.g. duplicaterule entity does not use it. For such entities we use modifiedon column.)

Here are some citations from $MS documentation:

- @@DBTS = The last-used timestamp value of the current database.
- MIN_ACTIVE_ROWVERSION = The lowest active rowversion value in the
  current database; @@DBTS + 1 if there are no active values in the
  database.
- A rowversion value is active if it is used in a transaction that has
  not yet been committed.